How to insert solution space after each part while using latex exam class?
While using the exam format, I have questions with several parts. So, each question looks like so:
\question Blah blah blah.
\begin{parts}
\part First blah?
\part Second blah?
\end{parts}

\begin{solution}[2in]
\begin{parts}
\part First answer
\part Second answer
\end{parts}
\end{solution}

When this is typeset, you get a space of 2in after both parts are stated. However, if I want space to be given after each part, how would you do it?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@cabobah i don't see how the space issue is addressed in the alleged duplicate. could you elaborate?

Thanks @cabohah. Though the question is different from that posted in your link, the answer is the same, i.e. putting the solution right below each part gets me what I need. Thanks a ton!
